# How to create trends in Sharepoint KPI based on Excel Data in Moss 2007

Tags: 2007, custom

How can i show trends (Arrows depicting relative performance) along with KPI's in Sharepoint . The KPI's have excel spreadsheet as their Datasource.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just create charts in the Excel files, give the charts a named range and publish it to SharePoint with Excel Services.  Then you can use a Excel Services web part to display the chart.

Another option if you're using Office 2010 is to use sparklines.  You could then do something similar like creating a pivot chart/table that shows the item and the sparkline.

You can't do any trending to my knowledge with the SharePoint KPI tools.  [Christophe](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2904/christophe) has done a lot with jQuery and visualizations to do things similar for users who don't have the Enterprise SKU.  You might want to review his [blog](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/), lots of good stuff there.

Comment: Hi PirateEEric, thats exactly what ive done , ive actually created pivot tables and charts (using office 2007) to allow filtering under excel services. Okay so im gonna take your word for it and say trends cant be created using only oob.